# RPI Docker does not restart containers after power failure

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

Have a RaspberryPi running Docker 17.11.0-ce, and Docker Compose 1.17.1.

I have a docker-compose file with two containers, both with restart-policy set to always.

On an initiated reboot from SSH the containers start up on boot as expected. 
 However, if I remove the power supply and re-instate, the RPI starts ok but the containers don't automatically start.

Have done this very thing on plenty of installations before and never encountered this.

Have I missed something?

UPDATE: It may be something in recent versions of Docker.  I have another system which works as expected, docker version is 17.06.0-ce.  I will try to revert systems and test again tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this issue is related to the specific version of docker (17.11).  Downgraded to 17.09 and return from power failure results in containers started as expected.

I have not experimented with other versions to determine exact release with issue, 17.09 is good enough for me.

Happy to provide any additional information if others would like to research further.

Kyle

Comment: I have the same exact issue running `Docker version 18.02.0-ce, build fc4de44`. I have some in swarm mode, and those come back up after hardware reset. But, the pis that are just running regular containers don't restart on power outage. My work around is to init a swarm and run the container as a service. Perhaps a little overhead if swarm features aren't being utilized, but it seems to work.

Comment: Having the same issue on up squared, 18.03